# Can't save WordPress post with "/etc/" in it

Tags: posts, content

In my self-hosted WordPress site, if I create a post with "/etc/" (without quotes) in it anywhere, I get a 404 Not Found when I save the post.

Wrap it in `<pre>` tags, or even escaping the characters (`&#47;&#101;&#116;&#99;&#47;`) doesn't work.

I've tried disabling all my plugins, but that doesn't make a difference.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: etc is a linux system directory; that's one reason why the slug is not allowed at that host.

Comment: yeah I realised that - however, I was writing a blog post about some shell scripts, so /etc/blahblah was included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ther is probably [`mod_security`](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modsecurity-htaccess-tricks.html) or a similar add-on installed on your web server. Find it, take the word `etc` out of the list of stop words.

WordPress doesn’t do that.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thanks. This site is on [shared hosting](http://www.nosupportlinuxhosting.com/), so I tried to try switching off mod_security rules in .htaccess using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928360/how-to-disable-mod-security-in-htaccess-file) but that didn't help. Though there is a comment on that answer saying that mod_security could have been compiled to prevent .htaccess overrides. Do you suppose there's anything else I could try?

Comment: @Ace Ask your web hosting support.

Comment: They're called No Support Linux Hosting :-), but thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!